# Concatenate strings in function call c++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a logger function where you can pass in a message which will be logged to a text file. Sometimes I'd like to pass in a variable concatenated with my message so I could do something like:

```
logger("The variable is: " + variable);
```

The function is defined as

```
void logger(std::string message);
```

I'm using Qt, so I don't know if it's relevant but the variable will always be a QString.
When I tried this it would say that no candidate function for

```
void logger(const QString);
```

So I thought why not make a second function where it would expect a concatenation:

```
void logger(std::string message);
void logger2(const QString message);
```

It compiled fine when I did

```
logger2("The variable is: " + variable);
```

However, when I debugged the passed message variable was an empty string.
How do I get this to work, is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean `const QString&`?

Comment: variable is almost always a QString. I would have done const QString& but the error message said I was doing const QString. Having const QString& doesn't work as "Text" + QString == const QString. If I do const QString& it doesn't compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just do something like this:

```
QString qs = "hello";
qs.toStdString();
```

As far as concatenating on the fly, I like to use a simple formatter class:

```
class Formatter
{
public:
    template<class Val> Formatter& operator<<(const Val& val)
    {
        ss_ << val;
        return * this;
    }
    operator string () const { return ss_.str().c_str(); }
private:
    std::stringstream ss_;
};
```

...which can be used like this:

```
logger(Formatter() << "The variable is: " << variable);
```

Comment: BTW, you can see a code review of my Formatter class here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226/does-my-class-introduce-undefined-behavior

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `logger("The variable is: " + variable.toStdString());`
 ?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. The QString include should do it.